# Google Sheets: averaging duration data per weekday

Tags: date, google-sheets, pivot-table

I've got date/ duration data, e.g.:

```
16-Apr  (Mon)  30mins

16-Apr  (Mon)  90mins

17 Apr (Tue) 60 mins

19-Apr (thu) 15 mins 

19-Apr (thu) 20 mins 

19-Apr (thu) 20 mins

21-April (Sat ) 120 mins  

23-April (Mon) 60 mins 

24-Apr (Tue)15 mins
```

I want to  produce an average duration per weekday

A pivot table with date can give me a sum of the durations for each date.

A pivot table on (derived) Day of the week gives me an average for the number of entries for that day of the week, e.g. in the above, Monday = 3 entries and I want an average from 2 (dates).

What I want is `Mondays = x mins`, `Tues= y mins`, `Wed =z mins`, etc.

Can this be done in one step with a pivot table or array formula?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have your dates in column E, and durations in F

This formula will give you a summary by day of week:

```
=query({arrayformula(weekday(E2:E7)), arrayformula(n(F2:F7))},
       "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1")
```

To get an average, use `avg(Col2)` instead of `sum(Col2)`. You still have to format the second result column as Duration, and find a way to convert the days of week from numeric to text, but that can be left as an exercise to the reader :-)

[image]

Comment: Ive tried this solution  here ( sorry , UK formatted dates)

Comment: I see this `n` function first time. Was it released recently?

Comment: Hi @MaxMakhrov, I think I've seen it since forever although it's the first time I had to use it, QUERY() did not want to sum the Duration values without it, even though in theory Duration values are numbers underneath.

Comment: still strugglng with this  - is an alternative to have a query of a query ?

Comment: Hi @user358360, you wanted a solution, I quote, "Can this be done in one step with a pivot table or array formula?"  You got 2 answers expressing a solution with a single formula. What's the problem you are struggling with exactly?

Comment: A table of date/duration  entries  - variable number of entries  per day
I want the average duration by day of the week

Comment: A table of date/duration  entries  - variable number of entries  per day
I want the average duration by day of the week16-Apr  (Mon)  30mins     
     
+16-Apr  (Mon)  90mins

    
+17 Apr (Tue) 60 mins   


+19-Apr (thu) 15 mins    


+19-Apr (thu) 20 mins      


+19-Apr (thu) 20 mins     


+21-April (Sat ) 120 mins       


+23-April (Mon) 60 mins 

     
+24-Apr (Tue)15 mins


output 

     
*Mon  30+90+60=180 mins over 2 days = 90 mins


*Tue  60+15 mins over 2 days =75/2 =37.5 


*Thu 20+20+20 over 1 day = 60 mins 


*Sat  120 mins

Comment: output  

     
*Mon  30+90+60=180 mins /2 days = 90 mins : 
Tue  60+15 mins over 2 days =75/2 =37.5  :

: Thu 20+20+20 over 1 day = 60 mins  :

Sat  120 mins

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to add labelling

```
=ArrayFormula(query({hlookup(weekday(A:A),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7;"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},2,false),B:B},"select Col1,avg(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Day'"))
```

[image]

The day numbers in column C are just for checking.

If any of the dates are missing, you need to ignore them otherwise they will all be treated as Saturdays...

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A:A,hlookup(weekday(A:A),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7;"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},2,false),B:B},"select Col2,avg(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label Col2 'Day'"))
```

**EDIT**

OK this is an answer for the actual requirement which is for sum of time durations for each weekday but divided by number of unique dates which fall on that weekday.

```
=ArrayFormula(query({query({C2:C,weekday(C2:C),choose(weekday(C2:C),"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"),E2:E},"select Col3,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2,Col3"),
query({unique(C2:C),weekday(unique(C2:C))},"select count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2")},"Select Col1,Col2/Col3 label Col1 'Day',Col2/Col3 'Average'"))
```

[image]

*Notes*

(1) The number of groups based on unique dates is exactly the same as the number of groups based on dates with duplicates.

(2) To get the day names in the correct order (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday...) I grouped on weekday number (1-7) then weekday name (Col2,Col3 in the first inner query). This doesn't create any more groups than just using Col3, but has the effect of putting the days in weekday number order instead of weekday name (alphabetical) order while still allowing you to put Col3 (weekday name) in the select list.

(3) Have included @ttarchala's recommendation of using Choose rather than Hlookup.

Comment: I'd use CHOOSE(), simpler than HLOOKUP() in this basic case.

Comment: Yes I thought at the time that HLOOKUP looked a bit long-winded.

Comment: <img src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MKLoAuzjNo7P1c0a5jeRNIM5cThaxHZx"  

=ArrayFormula(query({A:A,hlookup(weekday(C:C),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7;"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},2,false),E:E},"select Col2,avg(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label Col2 'Day'"))<br>
  Apologies for the UK time format

Comment: Apl;ogies - struggling with the editing /formatting . Perhaps a mod can delete the  nonsense ? 

<img src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MKLoAuzjNo7P1c0a5jeRNIM5cThaxHZx"  >

` =ArrayFormula(query({A:A,hlookup(weekday(C:C),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7;"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},2,false),E:E},"select Col2,avg(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label Col2 'Day'"))  `<br>
  Apologies for the UK time format

But there are 2 tuesdays  -13th&20th -  total time = 150 mins so the avg  i want is  72.5 . And 21st , the only wednesday , should be 150.

Comment: Ah I see - I totally misunderstood the question - so you want total time for a certain day of the week divided by number of different dates for that day of the week. Will have to think about that one.

Comment: I think I can see how to do it - will try and post something later.